# Adding a listView between two elements

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I would like to add an listView between a top and a bottom button. I don't want it to have a fixed size, so I tried to set it like this way:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" />

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button2
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

But when setting the layout file this way, the listview is of course below the 1st button, but goes from there down to the button of the screen, without stopping above the button2.
--> The listview overlaps the button2.

How can i place the listview between these two buttons?

Comment: something like this? http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:layout_above="@+id/button2"` attribute to the `ListView` as follows...which will keep the `ListView` above the `button2`.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Comment: This solution is perfectly fine but just as a side note if you don't really need the outer RelativeLayout for anything else the LinearLayout version with the height to 0 ant the weight is a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do the job

```
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:weight="1"/>

     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" />

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works perfect as per your requirement. It was quite simple...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` and for `ListView` you can set position by parameters `layout_above` and `layout_below`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert your xml into RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" />

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button2
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set this property to your listview

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2" />
```